# Make a long-work async nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am a newbie in nodejs. 
In my program, I need to resolve a long-work async.
I tried my code:

```
function testAsync(callback){
    //do long-work
    for(var i=0;i<1000000000;i++){
        //do-nothing, just pseudo a long work
    }
    //callback
    callback();
}
testAsync(function(){
    console.log("test");
});
console.log('main');
```

But when I am running testAsync, "test" always prints before "main", that means long-work runs synchronously.
So, how do I run long-work in async?

**EDIT**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/32b0nwwr6r0x2zk/jsonschemavalidator.js?dl=0

I created a validateAndConvert function to validate input from client request. I hope it is run asynchronously, but seems it run synchronously

Comment: You don't just "make" synchronous code asynchronous - it has to be an asynchronous operation to begin with. A for loop, for example, is CPU-bound so can't trivially be run asynchronously. What is the *actual* code you are trying to make asynchronous?

Comment: Yes @AntP . This code is synchronous in nature.

Comment: @AntP you can see my code at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/32b0nwwr6r0x2zk/jsonschemavalidator.js?dl=0

Comment: I'm trying code validateAndConvert function in async, but seems it run synchronous

Answer (score 2):

> how do I run long-work in async?

You can *schedule* the work to be started asynchronously, but when it's started later, it will still tie up the only thread Node runs the JavaScript code on. That is, you'll just block the thread later rather than right now. Synchronous work is synchronous work.

Assuming that isn't what you want to do, you have two main choices:

1. Break up the work into smaller pieces and schedule each piece asynchronously, so you're allowing other operations to be interspersed with handling those pieces of work.
2. Offload the work to a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: I edited my question, upload my actual code. Can you review my code and give me some advice?

Comment: @MinhGiang: Sorry, the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers uses to people in the future; and separately, people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: @MinhGiang: Then it's your job to create a [mcve]. But at this point, *this* question is answered. If you need help implementing one of the solutions above, once you've given it a go if you run into trouble, post a question asking about that (with an [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider removing this long-running task from your main application? A good design would be to create another node app, a worker, which would complete this task (PDF generation, image processing, etc.) completely separated. The communication between the two apps would be done with a queue.

This way you can also scale the app better.

A great post about SOA and microservices: https://blog.risingstack.com/why-you-should-start-using-microservices/